# In how many ways on can fill a matrix by +1 and -1

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can one fill an $n \times n$ matrix with $+1$ and $-1$ so that the product of the entries in each row and each column equals to $-1$?
What will be the case when the product of the entries in each row and each column equals to $1$?
Please help me to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to fix the principal minor $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ and complete the rest

Comment: Please post what you have tried to do to solve your problem. Then we can help you.

Comment: Can you do the cases $n=1$ and $n=2$? That would give you the idea! And also dispel the thought that you want somebody to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 2):

Choose $a_{ik}\in\{{-1},1\}$ for $1\leq i\leq n-1$and $1\leq k\leq n-1$ to your liking. The last entries $a_{in}$ $(1\leq i\leq n-1)$ and $a_{nk}$ $(1\leq k\leq n-1)$ are then determined by the condition that all row-products and all column-products should be $=-1$. Now check how many choices are left for  $a_{nn}$.

Comment: I didn't quite understand your answer, can you elaborate?